# Display both null and not null under same id but not both null or not null like XOR logic

Tags: select, query, null

Consider the following `Employee` table:

> [image: Employee table]

In this table I need to select only the ids which have both null and not null marks, and it should not be both not null or both are null in `col1`.

Comment: Are there instances of ID's having only a single entry, whether it is `NULL` or a non-`NULL` value? What about duplicate non-`NULL` values, such as two records with `10` and a third record with `NULL`?

Answer (score 2):

```
Select NullTest.ID, NullTest.Col1
    From NullTest 
    Join (Select ID From NullTest Where Col1 Is Not Null Group By ID) 
         NotNulls 
         On NotNulls.ID = NullTest.ID
    Join (Select ID From NullTest Where Col1 Is Null Group By ID) 
         Nulls 
         On Nulls.ID = NullTest.ID ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table 
where id in ( select id from table where col1 is     null 
              intersect 
              select id from table where col1 is not null 
            )

select t1.* from table t1
where exists ( select 1 from table where id = t1.id and col1 is     null )    
  and exists ( select 1 from table where id = t1.id and col1 is not null )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options, both based on using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`. The syntax is for Microsoft SQL Server but should be easily adaptable to any other RDBMS syntax.

```sql
/* SETUP: Run the following once */
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (ID INT NOT NULL, Col1 INT NULL);
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, Col1) VALUES (100, NULL);
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, Col1) VALUES (100, 10);
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, Col1) VALUES (101, NULL);
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, Col1) VALUES (101, NULL);
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, Col1) VALUES (102, 14);
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, Col1) VALUES (102, 11);
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, Col1) VALUES (103, NULL);
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, Col1) VALUES (103, 12);
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, Col1) VALUES (103, NULL);
/* END SETUP */


SELECT td.ID, td.Col1
FROM   #TestData td
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT tmp.ID, MAX(tmp.Col1) AS [Col1]
            FROM   #TestData tmp
            GROUP BY tmp.ID
            HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN tmp.Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
           ) ids
        ON ids.ID = td.ID;

-- This method appears to be better on SQL Server
SELECT td.ID, td.Col1
FROM   #TestData td
WHERE  td.ID IN (
            SELECT tmp.ID
            FROM   #TestData tmp
            GROUP BY tmp.ID
            HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN tmp.Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
           );
```

To be fair, and because I was curious about the `INTERSECT` approach [proposed by @Paparazzi](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/137644/30859), I tested both of @Paparazzi's methods along with the two shown above. I also wrapped it and each of the two methods shown above in `SET STATISTICS TIME, IO` On and Off, and ended with a `PRINT` to more clearly separate the test output in the "Messages" tab.

```sql
SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON;

SELECT td.ID, td.Col1
FROM   #TestData td
WHERE  td.ID IN (
                 SELECT ID FROM #TestData WHERE Col1 IS     NULL
                 INTERSECT
                 SELECT ID FROM #TestData WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL
                );

SET STATISTICS TIME, IO OFF;
PRINT '----------------------------------';

SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON;

SELECT td.ID, td.Col1
FROM   #TestData td
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TestData WHERE ID = td.ID AND Col1 IS NULL)
  AND  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TestData WHERE ID = td.ID AND Col1 IS NOT NULL)

SET STATISTICS TIME, IO OFF;
PRINT '----------------------------------';
```

Results:

```
Which Test:                  Query Cost    Scan Count   Logical Reads
GROUP BY via INNER JOIN      54%            2            2
GROUP BY via IN list         11%           10           10
INTERSECT                    17%            3           17
EXISTS                       18%            3           17
```

**Conclusion (thus far)**

It is hard to say at the moment considering that the results are the same across all 4 methods tested above, but the logic is different and would produce slight different results if some test cases were added, such as an `ID` having 3 records and two of them were `NOT NULL` (for Col1) but different, or having 3 records and two of them were `NOT NULL` but they were the same value. Or what if there are cases with either a single record of `NULL` or a single `NOT NULL` record? Without additional input / clarification from the O.P. we can only assume that those other cases might never happen.

Also, while the `IN` list method has the lowest Query Cost, that is based on the Estimated Cost which is not necessarily a reliable indicator. The `INNER JOIN` method has the lowest number of scans and logical reads, but this is also a rather small data set to test with. Again, further clarification would help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39370/discussion-on-answer-by-srutzky-display-both-null-and-not-null-under-same-id-but).

Answer (score 2):

`count(column)` and `count(*)` will differ if NULL exists:

```
SELECT ID, Col1 
FROM #TestData
WHERE id IN 
 (
   SELECT id
   FROM #TestData
   GROUP BY id
   HAVING COUNT(*) > COUNT(Col1) -- at least one NULL 
      AND COUNT(Col1) > 0        -- at least one NOT NULL
 )
```

Most DBMSes support Analytical Functions, if the data is result of a more complex query this might be more efficient because it avoids accessing the same table twice:

```
SELECT ID, Col1
FROM 
 (
   SELECT ID, Col1,
      COUNT(Col1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS cntNotNull,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS cntNull
   FROM #TestData AS t
 ) AS dt
WHERE cntNull > cntNotNull
  AND cntNotNull > 0
```